# Ruby on Rails: Is it a security issue to display data from sessions or cookies in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, cookies

I'm thinking about storing data in cookies as a way of managing state and then displaying this data in a view. My primary concern is security, is using values stored in cookies at the view level a bad idea? Can application users edit the cookie to leak ENV variables? The code:

```
Controller: 
@foo = cookies[:foo]

View: 
<h2> <%= @foo %> </h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your use case, in general I would say displaying the contents of cookies is not a good idea. Cookies are stored in the browser, and the user could theoretically alter their cookies and therefore change your app's behavior. The data will also be destroyed if the user resets their browser or clears their cookies.

Cookies are usually used to identify the browser session. The cookie is stored in the browser, but the session information is stored in server memory. If your goal is to display ephemeral info to the user, you could do this safely by storing the information in the session:

```rb
# Controller: 
session[:foo] = "something ephemeral"

# View: 
<h2>Your ephemeral data is: <%= session[:foo] %> </h2>
```

If you're looking for something longer-lasting, then consider adding a column to the `User` model, or creating a relation that will store the data in the database.

Comment: Can't sessions also be modified by the user? I though a session was just a special type of cookie.

Comment: By default Rails' CookieStore saves the session_id in the browser cookies, and then uses that to look up the session data saved in the server memory. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session. You can store additional data in the cookie but it isn't recommended. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage